# Redirect help from old domain to new domain, using cname www, but use htaccess to exclude specific directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We moved our website from our server, domainname.com to another server (a SaaS). We pointed the www via CNAME record in WHM (in order to preserve the MX and other services on the "old" server)
ALL www.domain.com traffic is now sent to the new SaaS. Works great.

For non-www links, we are using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.domainname\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and that works great too.

WE ALSO own domain-name.com, and that also lives on the "old" server.
domain-name.com is a misspelling of our company name, and we want all traffic from www and non-www.domain-name to 301 to domainname.com

That is easy too! In the domain-name .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.domainname.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Now the fun (and where I could use some help) --

We have many existing links, such as:

```
www.domainname.com/images/foldername1/image_300x300.png
www.domainname.com/images/foldername2/image_300x300.png
www.domainname.com/html_pages/page1.html
www.domainname.com/html_pages/page2.html
```

etc... And I'd really like to preserve these without getting sent to the new SaaS and thereby 404ing.

OR -- as an option, the entire contents of www.domainname.com has been cloned to www.domain-name.com -- so we could 301

```
http://www.domainname.com/images/foldername1/image_300x300.png to
http://www.domain-name.com/images/foldername1/image_300x300.png
```

and that would be perfect too... Actually, that would be preferred.

I have tried a dozen suggestions from other doing global redirects... but because the primary www.domainname.com is getting its redirect from CNAME, and we MUST trap for non-www in domainname.com's htaccess, HOW can we constrain specific directories (www or not) to 301 to a new server AND also force www.domain-name.com (and non-www) to 301 to www.domainname.com (unless the path is

```
/images/
/html_pages/
/secret_hiding_place/
```

Any ideas?
Also have to be careful for 301 loops.

Thanks for any clues or ideas.

THANKS!!!
J

Comment: Hi @carpeperdiem, were you able to solve this issue?